# RubyMine: javascript event deprecated?

Tags: javascript

is "event" deprecated?

IDE is RubyMine

many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you pass `event` as an argument to the handler and refer to that in the function body? Currently you are not passing the event to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead passing the change event object to the handler function arguments and referring to that instead in the handler function:

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  // ...
});
```

Otherwise you are referring to [Window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) which is not recommended to use to refer to the current event.